# Azure Cli - Pipe value and use it

Tags: azure-cli

I am trying to get a resource groupe name with the following

```
az group list --query "[?starts_with(name,'sieraccrea') ].name" --output tsv
```

which is successful and returns a value

> output is : sieraccrearg123

which I need to pipe to a delete command as follows

```
az group list --query "[?starts_with(name,'sieraccrea') ].name" --output tsv | az group delete --name $_ --no-wait --yes
```

I get this error:

> ERROR: argument --name/-n/--resource-group/-g: expected one argument

What is wrong with this pipeline? Thanks

Comment: Why not you are trying `az group delete -n MyResourceGroup`

Comment: I can but I need to automate deletion of several Resource groups as I do trainings and create several RG per day so I dont want to hard code the RG name

Comment: Then you may need to use foreach loop instead ,i was trying the same as of your command and got  `-tsv resource group not found`

Comment: With az group list --query "[?starts_with(name,'sieraccrea') ].name" --output tsv it works fine (dont forget the space inside ") ].name" between ) ], it is important to make the command work

Answer (score 0):

***We have tried the same to delete resource group with pipe using cli and it works fine*** ,

*To do this operation for best practice and to get it work smoothly make sure that your resource group is not contains any resources while deletion.*

- *Create sample resource group for testing and tried with your list and deletion command with some modification in your script and applied.*

***Here is the cmdlts:-***

```
$ az group list --query "[?starts_with(name, 'rgname') ].name" -o tsv | xargs -otl az group delete -n $_ --no-wait  -n
```

***OUTPUT SCREENSHOT FOR REFERENCE:-***

[image]

**NOTE:-** *Please make sure that the resource group we mentioned is available in Azure . Else you might encounter this issue. I got the same issue after deletion. Just run as it is and it occurs.*

*For more information please refer the below links:-*

- **Blog**|[***How to Delete Multiple Azure Resource Groups with Tags via bash az cli***](https://blog.jongallant.com/2020/05/azure-delete-multiple-resource-groups/) by @*jongallant*
- **MICROSOFT DOCUMENTATION**| [***`az group create`***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/group?view=azure-cli-latest#az-group-create) & [***`az group delete`***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/group?view=azure-cli-latest#az-group-delete).

Comment: Ajay, thanks, but I am not using az cli in bash shell, I am using it in my local powershell 7 terminal

Comment: Have you tried the same in your local PowerShell

Comment: And also make sure that you are using updated cli version in your local.

Comment: I have responded to you, with screenshot hereabove, it does not work in Az cli in local powershell 7 ternminal

Comment: Have you updated to the latest version az cli.!?